# Unable to merge xlsx files in R

Tags: r, merge, xlsx

Every time I try to merge the xlsx files, I get an error.
Ps: Apologies as I am new to this.

```
setwd("E:/IA/RBuilds/Consolidation") #folder with spreadsheets
library(readxl)
data.files = list.files()
df <- readxl::read_excel(data.files[1], sheet=1) #reading the first file of list
for (file in data.files[-1]) {
  newFile <- readxl::read_excel(file, sheet=1)[-1,] ## Drops the first row
  df <- merge(df, newFile, all=T)
}
```

Error: Can't establish that the input is either xls or xlsx.

Comment: Have you tried `dplyr` `join`? https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/join.html

Comment: @joran Files are of xlsx format and I verified that from the file properties. And no the files aren't corrupt.

Comment: @ThomasFuchs I will look into it. But still wanted to understand why this is not working.

Comment: I suggest using `list.files(pattern=".*\\.xlsx?$")`, as it will preclude accidentally including inappropriate files. For instance, is there a sub-directory in there?

Comment: Have a look at the **data.files**. There must exist a document which is neither .`xls` nor `.xlsx`

Comment: More specifically (@joran is right, of course): the error is coming from `readxl:::check_format`, which uses two methods: (1) file extension, and (2) reading the first 8 bytes and checking the signature. If the first fails, it (by default) tries the second. If the second fails, then perhaps (a) it isn't an excel file, (b) it's corrupted, or (c) it's a new format that Hadley should probably hear about.

Comment: SANYAM, I'm inclined to believe that this is just a clerical error, that there are non-excel files in your `data.files`, as `readxl::` is pretty good about determining file formats. If (as @maydin suggested) `all(grepl("xlsx?$",data.files))` is not true, then you have found your culprit. Otherwise, it might help you to find out which file is failing (likely the value of `file` when you get that error), and verify that you can open it in Excel (or Calc or ...).

Comment: Just to make you be convinced, I run the code `readxl::read_excel("./desktop/test.txt", sheet=1)[-1,]`  in my R session. And It gave, *Error: Can't establish that the input is either xls or xlsx.* Because I tried to call a `.txt` file in `read_excel `. You need to follow @r2evans comment.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following function to merge two Excel files :

```
library(RDCOMClient)
merge_Two_Excel_Files <- function(path_Excel_File1,
                                  path_Excel_File2,
                                  path_Excel_File_Output)
{
  xlApp <- COMCreate("Excel.Application")
  xlWbk1 <- xlApp$Workbooks()$Open(path_Excel_File1)
  xlWbk2 <- xlApp$Workbooks()$Open(path_Excel_File2)
  nb_Sheets1 <- xlWbk1$Sheets()$Count()
  nb_Sheets2 <- xlWbk2$Sheets()$Count()

  for(l in 1 : nb_Sheets1)
  {
    wbSheet <- xlWbk1$Worksheets(l)$Copy(after = xlWbk2$Worksheets(l))
  }

  xlWbk2$SaveAs(path_Excel_File_Output)
  xlWbk1$Close()
  xlWbk2$Close()
  xlApp$Quit()

  rm(list = ls())
  gc()
}
```